# ng-focus and ng-blur events not triggering in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
<input type='text' ng-focus='tryFunc()'> </input>
```

The function `tryFunc()` is not called when the input box is focused.

I am including `jQuery.min.js` in the file and it is before `angular.min.js`  jQuery is version v1.10.2 and Angular.js is v1.0.7.

What may be happening?

Comment: For anyone else arriving here looking for a working example of ng-focus / ng-blur in 1.2.x: http://jsfiddle.net/b8zRG/1/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

ngFocus is not available on Angular 1.0.7. It's available on Angular 1.2.

You can create your own ngFocus directive, it's quite simple, have a look here:

https://gist.github.com/eliotsykes/5394631

Comment: the website is still giving out 1.0.7. Is 1.2 available? is it stable?

Comment: It's not stable yet, they released an rc1 version: http://blog.angularjs.org/2013/08/angularjs-120-rc1-spooky-giraffe.html

Answer (score 1):

works with version 1.2.17 
See demo

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/35636e7c020d50aeab18