# What is the easiest way to put a default focus on an element in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have a template that is loaded in a modal dialog, there is a single input text on it which I would like to have a focus on. What is the easiest and the Angular way of doing that?

**Update**:

This is in part answered in [How to set focus on input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833326)

Comment: You can use `ng-focus` depending on the version of angular you are using. As the poster in the following question states you can create your own ng-focus directive. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18549142/ng-focus-and-ng-blur-events-not-triggering-in-angularjs

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/14837021/215945 which deals with setting focus inside a modal dialog.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Depending on the browser(s) you need to support you could use [input autofocus attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autofocus.asp).

See plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/LWjNTU).

Or if this is not an option and has mentioned by Mark you can refer to the following [stackoverflow response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833326/how-to-set-focus-in-angularjs/14837021#14837021).

Comment: The Plunk does not work (anymore) in the sense that it does not put the focus on the edit box.

Comment: if $uibmodal then use autoficus attribute else if custom directive use element[0].focus() in link

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

**HTML**

```
  <div ng-controller="ctrl as vm" ng-init="vm.focus();">
<form name="Form">
  <input type="text" id="input1">
  <input type="text" id="input2">
</form>
```

**JS**

```
   angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.focus = function() {
      document.getElementById('input2').focus();
    }; 
  });
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/noLUjVjycpnezpvEIgw7?p=preview

Comment: Does not seem to work, either in my code or the plunker, either in the embedded preview or in a separate window: the two inputs show up, but the second is not focused. Breakpoint indicates the focus function is never called.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I've found is to call focus inside a $timeout wrap.

Controller:

```
$timeout(function () { $('#input1').focus(); });
```