# How to set the validation on blur event?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-validation

I have wrriten some sample in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cA8Stcww0mMWKTvEV1ut?p=preview). I need to validate my input when the user leaves it. I used `ng-model-options="{ updateon: 'blur'}"` for this. `ng-minlength` works fine but this doesn't apply to the `ng-required` validation.

Comment: Its working in the plunker. required validation is fired when the field is empty.

Comment: but it fires right away, I want to see the error after I leave the input

Comment: No it fires only when its empty and You click some where else.Otherwise if it is empty and focus is on it ,it doesn't show error

Comment: but the error message shows on startup and I don't want that. It should validate the first time when the event 'blur' occurs.

Comment: See this similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18549142/ng-focus-and-ng-blur-events-not-triggering-in-angularjs

Comment: so you suggest to write a custom validation directive?

Comment: <div ng-show="myForm.input.$invalid && myForm.input.$dirty"> add this before <span ng-if="myForm.input.$error.required">You didn't enter a value</span> <span ng-if="myForm.input.$error.minlength">to short</span> and close div after that

Answer (score 1):

(edited, removed another example as it was confusing)

Try $touched.

I have forked your Plunk

http://plnkr.co/edit/tt5A1DUjmq07TiEKhtNP?p=preview

I have also added two fields so you can see it work, eg tab from one to the other.

HTML

```
<input name="inputA" type="text" ng-model="valueA" ng-required="true" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}" ng-minlength="3" />
<span ng-if="myForm.inputA.$error.required && myForm.inputA.$touched">You didn't enter a value</span>
<span ng-if="myForm.inputA.$error.minlength">to short</span>
<br/>
<input name="inputB" type="text" ng-model="valueB" ng-required="true" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}" ng-minlength="3" />
<span ng-if="myForm.inputB.$error.required && myForm.inputB.$touched">You didn't enter a value</span>
<span ng-if="myForm.inputB.$error.minlength">to short</span>
```

Comment: what do I have to put as `mainForm` - the name of my form, so `myForm`? as `[field.Name]` u mean the input name - `input`? because i don't get this notation..

Comment: for your code its just myForm.input.$touched , our forms are generated from data hence my [field.Name] , sorry I should have made that clear

Comment: I did try it on your plunk as per first code example

Comment: The best answer to this question would be if someone would show a way to apply the `ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}"` to the required validation... I don't know why angular doesn't allow this :/ cause then the error flag would be set and also the `ng-invalid-required` css class.

Comment: does the $touched not work? it works fine on your plunk, the updateOn only updates the model 'on' validation happens on the form, if you add {{myForm.input}} you can see other things happening .

Comment: also, have a look at docs on allowInvalid

allowInvalid: boolean value which indicates that the model can be set with values that did not validate correctly instead of the default behavior of setting the model to undefined.

Comment: I will take a look today at it and see what happens ;)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should use **updateOn**

```
ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}"
```

along with

```
novalidate=""
```

on the form

Answer (score 0):

If you add `ng-focus="blur = false" ng-blur="blur=!blur"`to the input and change the `ng-if` to `"myForm.input.$error.required && blur">`  the message will disappear when the input regains focus and appear on blur if empty.